# Limiting number of output pages

Tags: output

I've a class file that my students have to use to write their final year report using LaTeX.

Students are told that their report must not exceed 50 pages and that any page beyond this limit will not be read.

However, it would be nice if I could include a mechanism to prevent their PDF to contain pages beyond page 50 (i.e. discarding excess pages). I wonder if there is a way to do that.

Comment: In the class, add `\RequirePackage[-50]{pagesel}`, similar to the suggestion [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180770/5764).

Comment: Possible duplicate: Adding a cost of extra pages / forcing a page limit

Comment: @Werner, @ Christian. Thanks. I have looked at the package an tried with the additional option `nonofile`. This works but creates blank pages at the end of the PDF in place of the discarded ones (but I only had a quick look at the package).

Comment: @Werner There seem to be some small incompatibility with my class file. If I use a very simple article document `pagesel` discard the excess pages, but with my class file it replaces them with blank pages. Have you seen that before?

Comment: @Pierre: I'll just be guessing until you give access to the class file... Consider using [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: @Werner. Fair enough. My class file being quite large I am going to investigate a bit to narrow the problem down first.

Comment: @Werner. The problem was not in my style file. I am going to post a new question with minimal example.

Comment: @Werner. I have posted about the problem at (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181263/incompatibility-between-pagesel-and-pfggantt)