# Incompatibility between pagesel and pgfgantt

Tags: incompatibility

The following code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[-6,nonofiles]{pagesel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

works fine, but if you comment out the fourth line the PDF produced includes a blank page for each discarded page. Any solution/explanation to this problem?

A fix is to place `\usepackage{pgfgantt}` before `\usepackage[-6,nonofiles]{pagesel}`, but still some explanation would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the loading order and you'll get the expected output:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[-6,nonofiles]{pagesel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll have to dig through [`pgfgantt`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt) to find any incompatibility.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had also found the fix as mentioned in the second part of my question. but I suppose you were writing the answer while I was editing the question.

Comment: @Pierre: [`pgfgantt`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt) loads [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) (of PGF). And I know PGF has the ability to overlay elements onto the page - something that is done during the shipout routine. My guess is [`pagesel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pagesel)'s use of [`everyshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pagesel) should be inserted *before* `tikz` gets a change to modify this output routine, causing the incompatibility.